# How to install linux on odroid-U3(or other odroid version)?

Tags: archlinux, odroid

I have an odroid-U3, and I don't know how to install a linux on it, can anyone tell me how to do it? and I have another question, can odroid-U3 powered by USB port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the official guide at [archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv7/samsung/odroid-u3](http://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv7/samsung/odroid-u3)

Note: If you stuck at step 7 when performed

```
cd root/boot
./sd_fusing.sh /dev/sdX
cd ../..
```

you can open the file `sd_fusing.sh`, change the line

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
```

into

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Grab the appropriate linux distro from:

```
http://os.archlinuxarm.org/os/
```

or follow the steps below which will use the U2 image which is the same for U3:

**SD Card Creation**
Replace sdX in the following instructions with the device name for the SD card as it appears on your computer.

```
Zero the beginning of the SD card:
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=1M count=8
Start fdisk to partition the SD card:
fdisk /dev/sdX
At the fdisk prompt, create the new partitions:
Type o. This will clear out any partitions on the drive.
Type p to list partitions. There should be no partitions left.
Type n, then p for primary, 1 for the first partition on the drive, and enter twice to accept the default starting and ending sectors.
Write the partition table and exit by typing w.
Create and mount the ext4 filesystem:
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdX1
mkdir root
mount /dev/sdX1 root
Download and extract the root filesystem (as root, not via sudo):
wget http://archlinuxarm.org/os/ArchLinuxARM-odroid-u2-latest.tar.gz
bsdtar -xpf ArchLinuxARM-odroid-u2-latest.tar.gz -C root
Flash the bootloader files:
cd root/boot
./sd_fusing.sh /dev/sdX
cd ../..
Unmount the partition:
umount root
Insert the SD card into the board, connect ethernet, and apply 5V power.
Use the serial console (with a null-modem adapter if needed) or SSH to the IP address given to the board by your router.
Login as the default user alarm with the password alarm.
The default root password is root.
```

**eMMC Module Creation**

Attach the eMMC module to the micro SD adapter, and plug that into your computer.
Follow the above steps to install Arch Linux ARM, and boot the board with the eMMC still attached to micro SD adapter, plugged into the SD slot in the board.
Re-flash the bootloader to the protected boot area of the eMMC module:

```
cd /boot
./sd_fusing.sh /dev/mmcblk0
Power off the board:
poweroff
Remove the micro SD adapter, detach the eMMC module, and connect the eMMC module to its connector on the board.
Re-apply power the board.
Use the serial console (with a null-modem adapter if needed) or SSH to the IP address given to the board by your router.
Login as the default user alarm with the password alarm.
The default root password is root.
```